# Finding busiest flight route in india

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So I have to find busiest flight route in india from given csv file:

[image]

This data set is of 300k data. So I need to find busiest route and plot it. Let me show you my code:

```
# Importing Libarires
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("Dataset.csv")

df['count'] =1       #initially, set that counter to 1.
group_data = df.groupby(['source_city','destination_city'])['count'].sum() #sum function
result = group_data.sort_values(ascending=False)
result
```

I'm unable to get the data and unable to store city name and count.

**Please help me with this!**

**Output of trying**:

```
group_data = df.groupby(['source_city','destination_city']).count()
```

[image]

Comment: `flights = pd.crosstab(df['source_city'], df['destination_city'])`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
group_data = df.groupby(['source_city','destination_city']).count()
```

Comment: Hey! I tried but I'm getting a table of all information and count value repeated many times. You can see output above

Comment: all are the same. just take the column count

Comment: you can also add as_index=False in the groupby if you don't want multi-level index